# How do you do retrieve records based on a child elements' condition?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, orm

I have a model AvailableSlot with attribute "max_attendees". AvailableSlot has_many BookedSlots.

I am looking for all AvailableSlots that are still available (where the booked_slots is less than max_attendees")

I tried

```
scope :with_capacity, -> { joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN booked_slots on booked_slots.available_slot_id = available_slots.id')
.group('available_slots.id').having("booked_slots.count < available_slots.max_attendees") }
```

and

```
  #AvailableSlot.rb
  def self.with_capacity
    self.select{ |s| s.booked_slots.count < s.max_attendees }
  end
```

but these return arrays, and the first one can't do a ".count", and the second solution can't do ".limit(3)" because the data that gets returned aren't active records.

One last question: for doing things like,

```
AvailableSlot.joins(:booked_slots).where("booked_slots.length < ?, max_attendees)
```

I can't use .length because that's not a column under booked_slots. What's a way to use this .joins.where format while using the activerecord methods like .count, .length, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a virtual attribute for the having.

```
AvailableSlot.
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN booked_slots on booked_slots.available_slot_id = available_slots.id').
  select('available_slots.*, count(booked_slots) as booked_slots_count').
  group('available_slots.id').
  having('booked_slots_count < max_attendees')
```

This will also expose a the virtual attribute to the model.

Mind that this will make it so `.count` is more complicated and you'll have to pass jazz to it, check out the options available on the doc: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods/count